# Almacenar un objeto en un arreglo de string

Tags: java

```
((Estudiente)oPersona).setEmpadronar((**Carrera**)vDatosRegistro[7]));
```

que puedo hacer para que no me de error al querer almacernar ese objeto en un array list de tipo string. El error lo de el objeto de tipo `Carrera`

Comment: Bro, lo unico que puedes tratar de hacer es castearlos a string para que te deje ingregarlo

Comment: ¿Por que deseas almacenarlo en un arraylist de string y no de Estudiente?

Comment: Intenta usar String.valueOf(...);